# popup window opens larger than intended dimensions

Tags: javascript, popup, window

I have been trying to figure out the following problem for way too long now and I can't seem to get a grip on what I'm doing wrong...

For my online portfolio, I have a splash "enter" image that is supposed to open a new window with a fixed size of 1013px for the width and 632px for the height. I chose this size for the window because this is the size of my background image and I am not intending on making the actual page scrollable. All of my content is supposed to just fit within the fixed window.

However, I'm noticing discrepancies among browsers. On my very own computer, a Macbook Pro, using a recent version of Safari, I keep on getting about 80+ pixels of white space underneath my background. On my girlfriend's computer, (also a Macbook Pro,) this problem also occurs. But, when I test the website on my iMac desktop, which happens to have Safari, Chrome, and Firefox all installed, the window opens up to the correct dimensions, with no extra white space. Finally, although I haven't been able to see it functioning in person, I've been told that there is white space added at the bottom AND on the right side of my background when the website is opened up on a Windows-based computer.

The link to the splash page is: http://www.jamesbarracca.com

Can you please tell me why I am having this issue? Thank you!

Comment: I forgot to mention: I'm very new to coding and creating websites. I never went to school for anything like this before and I've been trying to teach myself. So, please take into account that I am new to this.

Comment: Thank you! Were you able to see the problem I described?

Comment: If one of the answers below helped you to solve your problem, please consider marking it as "Accepted" by clicking the little checkbox below its score. If not, please provide us more details on what isn't working so we can help you further.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest altering your JavaScript to more tightly control the size of the pop-up window. What is likely happening is that in various different browsers, and on different machines, the default size for the popup is different.

Take a look at [this article](http://macboypro.wordpress.com/2009/05/16/pop-up-a-new-browser-window-with-a-fixed-size/) for an example.

Exerpt:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openpopup(address, width, height) {
        window.open(
            address, 
            "",
            "fullscreen=no,toolbar=no,status=no," + 
            "menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no," +
            "width=" + width + ",height=" + height
        );
    }
</script>
```

You can then call this new function with something like:

```
<a href="javascript: openpopup('http://www.google.com', '1013', '632')">
  <img src="/my/image/path.png" />
</a>
```

As you can see - the function allows you to specify things like the width and height of the popup, turn off its ability to have scrollbars / resizing, and so on. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you, Troy, but unfortunately, even after trying that, I'm still getting the extra white space underneath. (By the way, are you seeing white space when you open my popup window?)

Comment: No - your popup happens to come up at the right size on my browser - so I can not reproduce your error.

Comment: That's good to hear for sure. But, just out of curiosity, what browser and operating system are you running out of?